# как поссортировать массив относительно другого массива после его сортировки

Tags: javascript

У меня есть два массива:

```
var X = [0, 6, 10, 10, 6, 0, -6, -10, -10, -6];
var Y = [10, 8, 3, -3, -8, -10, -8, -3, 3, 8];
```

Числа с одинаковыми индексами у меня создают координату, например:

```
X[2] and Y[2] = (10, 3);
```

И вот какими эти пары сейчас есть, такими они и должны быть всегда.
Дальше я сортирую массив Y.

```
Y.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

И теперь пары у меня уже изменились. Как можно изменить массив X так, что бы пары были как в самом начале?

Comment: а какой смысл вообще сортировать?)

Comment: например я создаю таким способом фигуру, а дальше от самого верху должен соединить точки по порядку, что бы создать треугольники, а потом из заполнить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный ответ будет такой:

хранить эти данные сразу попарно в массиве объектов, т.е.:

```
let coords = [
    {x: 0, y: 6},
    {x: 12, y: -5},
    {x: -32, y: 12},
    ...
]
```

Если заходить дальше, то каждая пара - это новый класс `new Point(x, y)`.

---

И тут, если надо, можно отсортировать по любому ключу

Comment: а как сортировать такой массив, например на основе 'y'?

Comment: return a.y - b.y;